# how do write a sql query for pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination

When I'm selecting a query which has more than 600 records to display but I want select only a certain number of rows,and Total Count and RowNumber  ([1-20], [30-40])
and I need the answer in SQL

My Query is:

```
select * from employee_table
```

Answer (score 4):

This would get the first 0-10 records

```
select * from employee_table limit 0,10
```

This would get the first 10-20 records

```
select * from employee_table limit 10,10
```

And so-on

You can read about it here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

> Note that you really need to make sure there is an index that will help the ordering to avoid the LIMIT being a tad slow. Probably not an issue with a small number of records.
>   ~ [Kickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723545/kickstart)
>
> This *may* get the first 0-10 records, but in the absence of an ORDER BY clause it CANNOT be guaranteed.
>   ~ [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)

Comment: Good explanation +1, you awnsered it more clearly than I did so I removed my awnser

Comment: Note that you really need to make sure there is an index that will help the ordering to avoid the LIMIT being a tad slow. Probably not an issue with a small number of records.

Comment: Added it into my answer. Thanks @Kickstart

Comment: This *may* get the first 0-10 records, but in the absence of an ORDER BY clause it CANNOT be guaranteed.

Comment: @Strawberry very correct! I've added that to my answer :)